# Is it possible to show $ \bigcap_{ m\text{ : maximal ideal}} A_m = A$ without using the ideal of denominators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain.  A standard exercise is that 
$$A = \bigcap_{m\text{ maximal}} A_m$$
where we consider $A$ and $A_m$ as subrings of $A_{\{0\}} = K(A)$.
[A standard proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253186/how-to-show-bigcap-m-textrm-maximal-ideal-a-m-a) is by considering the ideal of denominators.

Assuming I don't know this proof, I may want to write an element in $K(A)$ by $\frac{a}{b}$ and try to prove 
if $\frac{a}{b} \in A_m$ for all $m$, then $b \mid a$ should hold. The assumption implies that $a \in m$ if $b \in m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal. One might hope that the last statement implies $b\mid a$ but that's not the case if $a$ and $b$ have nontrivial common divisors, for example, $\frac{4}{2}$.

My question is if there's a way to modify the expression of $\frac{a}{b}$ so this argument can work? I don't know much about general ring theory but I heard that $\gcd(a,b)$ is not well-defined in general. I wonder if there's some useful replacement for this notion?

Comment: It is true that $\gcd$ doesn't always make sense. For instance, in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ both $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$ are common divisors of $2+2\sqrt{-5}$ and $6$, but neither is a divisor of the other, so you can't say that one is greatest. As for what substitute you can use for $\gcd(a,b)$, we have for instance the ideal $(a,b)$, as well as the set of common divisors of $a$ and $b$. I don't know whether any of them are useful to you specifically.

Comment: In fact, I remember hearing that the term "ideal" arose in number theoory when ideals of number rings were originally viewed as "idealized elements" of the number ring, in order to overcome exactly this problem when there was not unique factorization.  (See also "Dedekind domain".)